# Out-of-range value when trying to filter on converted datetime value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to pull data for certain dates out of a staging table where the offshore developers imported everything in the file, so I need to filter out the "non-data" rows and convert the remaining strings to datetime.

Which should be simple enough but... I keep getting this error:

*The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.*

I've taken the query and pulled it apart, made sure there are no invalid strings left and even tried a few different configurations of the query. Here's what I've got now:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    select cdt = CAST(cmplt_date as DateTime), *
    from stage_hist

    WHERE cmplt_date NOT LIKE '(%'
    AND ltrim(rtrim(cmplt_date)) NOT LIKE ''
    AND cmplt_date NOT LIKE '--%'
) f
WHERE f.cdt BETWEEN '2017-09-01' AND '2017-10-01'
```

To make sure the conversion is working at least, I can run the inner query and the cast actually works for all rows. I get a valid data set for the rows and no errors, so the actual cast is working.

The BETWEEN statement must be throwing the error then, right? But I've casted both strings I use for that successfully, and even taken a value out of the table and did a test query using it which also works succesfully:

```
select 1
WHERE CAST('      2017-09-26' as DateTime) BETWEEN '2017-09-01' AND '2017-10-01'
```

So if all the casts work individually, how come I'm getting an out-of-range error when running the real query?

Comment: I was able to get the data by inserting into a table variable first, but still would like to know why I had to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that this is due to the fact that in your `cmplt_date` field there are values which are not valid dates. Yes, I know you are filtering them using a `WHERE` clause, but know that [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql) is not always the actual order. What does this mean is that sometimes, the SQL Engine my start performing your `CAST` operation before finishing the filtering.

You are using `SQL Server 2012`, so you can just add [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    select cdt = TRY_CAST(cmplt_date as DateTime), *
    from stage_hist

    WHERE cmplt_date NOT LIKE '(%'
    AND ltrim(rtrim(cmplt_date)) NOT LIKE ''
    AND cmplt_date NOT LIKE '--%'
) f
WHERE f.cdt BETWEEN '2017-09-01' AND '2017-10-01'
```